# ERROR: Service 'dash' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder134733065/app.py: no such file or directory in Windows 10

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  dash:
    build: ./docker
    environment:
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=false
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - c:/Users:/data
```

- Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /data

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY app.py ./ 

CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

doing a simple COPY command in Dockerfile is throwing this error when the file is in a folder (not same level as Dockerfile file)

My folder structure:

```
- docker
    - Dockerfile
    - requirements.txt  
- app
    - app.py
- docker-compose.yml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the error because the docker build context directory `./docker` on your host does not contains `app.py`.

Make sure `./docker` folder contains `app.py` file.

If you know the correct directory containing the build context and the app.py file then specify that directory as build context.

```
build: /path/to/build/context
```

More info about build context [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build).

To know what exactly is docker build context, check [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description).

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

After checking your folder structure it seems `app/app.py` is outside of `./docker` directory which is your build context.

Bring the app directory inside docker folder and change copy command to `COPY app/app.py ./`. Also change CMD to `CMD [ "python", "/data/app.py" ]`.

Comment: I have moved into docker folder but not working http://prntscr.com/on20sm @mchawre

Comment: Change this `CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]` to this `CMD [ "python", "/data/app.py" ]`. Let me know after running.

Comment: Same error: 
`dash_1  | python: can't open file '/data/app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
mgmt-dash_dash_1 exited with code 2`

Comment: Change COPY command to  `COPY app/app.py /data/`. Build and run it.

Comment: After you make any code change. You need to build `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up`

Comment: I have to follow `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up` but same error

Comment: First verify if that app.py exists inside docker image. After `docker-compose build` check the docker image `docker images` output. And run that docker image `docker run -itd image-name sh` You will enter inside the shell and know check where that app.py is located.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197358/discussion-between-raghav-rangani-and-mchawre).

Answer (score 1):

Using `COPY` and `ADD`, you can only use source files that are in the same folder as the `Dockerfile`, or in sub-folders:

> COPY obeys the following rules:
>
> - The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build
>     is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker
>     daemon.

(https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

In your case, `app.py` is in a sibling folder of `docker`, which is the base directory of your build context. You'll need to move `app.py` somewhere within the `docker` folder. For example:

```
- docker
    - Dockerfile
    - requirements.txt  
    - app
        - app.py
- docker-compose.yml
```

And adjust your Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /data

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY app/app.py ./ 

CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

Comment: I have added my folder structure in my question please check.

Comment: I have moved into docker folder but not working http://prntscr.com/on20sm

Comment: So if you `docker-compose exec [service name] sh` in to the container and do an `ls .`, does `app.py` appear?

Comment: dash in your case